# How to use Odata to filter query , to get the events from past 7 days until the following 28 days

Tags: filter, azure-functions, odata, azure-logic-apps

[image]

I am trying to filter the query in Odata in logic app.
as this is a calendar app, I want to get the events in the past 7 days and the following 28 days.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to filter query, you can achieve this taking `createdDateTime` variable and calculate for the expected results since `createdDateTime`'s format and the `utcNow()` format will be different. Now you need to convert both into one format and check for the difference. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

[image]

Below is the expression I have used to get the difference.

```
dateDifference(formatDateTime(outputs('Compose'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

For demonstration purpose I have taken the difference as 7 but you can mention as per your requirement.

Below is the complete code view of my logic app for your reference.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose_3": {
                "inputs": "@variables('data')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": "@items('For_each')?['createdDateTime']",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Compose_2": {
                        "inputs": "@dateDifference(formatDateTime(outputs('Compose'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd'))",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_array_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "data",
                                    "value": "@items('For_each')"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "lessOrEquals": [
                                        "@int(slice(outputs('Compose_2'),0,nthIndexOf(outputs('Compose_2'),'.',1)))",
                                        "@int('7')"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose_2": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Get_events_(V4)')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_events_(V4)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_events_(V4)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/calendars/v4/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('xxx'))}/items",
                    "queries": {
                        "$top": 10
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "data",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```